# Tell AuthLogic to not use a password confirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, user-experience, password-confirmation

I have this view:

### new.html.haml

```
%h1 New account

- form_for @user do |f|
  = f.error_messages
  = render :partial => "form", :object => f
  = f.submit "Create account"
```

### _form.html.haml

```
= form.label :email
= form.text_field :email
%br/
= form.label :password, form.object.new_record? ? nil : "Change password"
= form.password_field :password
```

Resulting in this evil error message:

> ## 1 error prohibited this user from being saved
>
> There were problems with the following fields:
>
> - Password confirmation is too short (minimum is 4 characters)

I don't want a password confirmation. Password confirmations suck and they prevent super-fast signing up, which is awesome! Can anyone explain me how to disable the password confirmation? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_authentic do |c|
    c.require_password_confirmation = false
  end
end
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://rdoc.info/rdoc/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/c52993c83479d614a18cc888a0ddc0a25b5afd8e/Authlogic/ActsAsAuthentic/Password/Config.html#require_password_confirmation-instance_method) for more details.

Comment: Harish, Can we disable password confirmation only for a certain case- Here is my question. Can you answer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24675303/authlogic-turn-off-require-password-confirmation-for-a-certain-case