# Authlogic turn off require_password_confirmation for a certain case

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, authlogic

I have an app that uses authlogic for login mechanism.

My sign up page requires no password confirmation but password reset page does.

```
acts_as_authentic do |a|
  a.require_password_confirmation = true
end
```

The above code turns on password confirmation for all the actions but which is not required in my case. It should be turned on when password reset is called and off when user signs up.

Is there a way to turn this on and off on a conditional basis ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Set password confirmation to false.

```
acts_as_authentic do |a|
  a.require_password_confirmation = false
end
```

Set the `password_confirmation` value in the `create` action of `UsersController`.

```
before_action :set_password_confirmation, :only => :create

def set_password_confirmation
  if params[:user] 
    params[:user][:password_confirmation] = params[:user][:password]
  end
end
```

Comment: This would be a crude way of doing that. I managed this with model validations and setting require_password_confirmation to false. I dont think we need filters to do that. I was thinking if we have any authlogic way of doing this. Thanks for the reply anyway